# What does mongoose.model() do? What does it return?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I want to know what mongoose.model() do? Also what does it mean to export it? Am I exporting a collection?

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const schema = mongoose.Schema;

    const userSchema = new Schema({
        firstName: {
            type: String
        },
        lastName: {
           type: String
        },

     })

    module.exports = User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Thanks.

Comment: model makes a copy of schema from what I know

Comment: Does it mean that User is a copy of the schema in my code?

Comment: mongoose.model() returns a Model ( It is a constructor, compiled from Schema definitions). Check mongoose docs for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mongoose.model compiles a Schema into a Model, then you can use its methods to access the database.
For example:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const dbURI = 'mongodb://localhost/YOURDB';

mongoose.connect(dbURI, {useNewUrlParser: true}).then(() => {
   console.log(`Mongoose connected to ${dbURI}`);
}).catch((err) => {
   console.log('Mongoose connection error:', err);
});

const yourSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      name: String,
});

const yourModel = mongoose.model('yourModel', yourSchema);
```

and with yourModel you can use CRUD methods to use Insert, Read, Update and Delete operations in YOURDB.

You can see [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) the helper functions for CRUD operations that Mongoose provides.

Comment: Does it create a collection in the database?

Comment: Yes, it does when you save your first document using the model.